# Jenkins workflow - filenotfound for workspace file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am trying to read a file in the workspace.  The file was created in a previous step (by a shell script call to java).  I've confirmed it exists.  I am using 'readFile'.  I get the exception below.  I can access this file in a shell script but I want to do some json parsing and would much rather use groovy.  Is there some security in play here preventing access?

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/MBTest/branches/develop/workspace/functional-tests/target/scalatestcuke-F63QUALZN4.json
(No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at hudson.FilePath.read(FilePath.java:1751)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ReadFileStep$Execution.run(ReadFileStep.java:87)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.ReadFileStep$Execution.run(ReadFileStep.java:81)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:213)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The Jenkinsfile (slightly cut down)

```
#!groovy
// Execute the following steps on the master


node {

 stage name: 'Checkout', concurrency: 1

 checkout scm
 functionalTest()
 release()
}


def functionalTest(){

 stage name: 'QA', concurrency: 1

 echo "nonrestF63"
 sh scalatestScript("F63QUALZN4","latest",5922,"-l jhc.TDRest")

 archive includes: 'functional-tests/target/*.json'

 def job = build job: 'generic-cucumber-report', parameters: [
   [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'projectname', value:  'MBTest/develop'],
   [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'jsondir', value: 'functional-tests/target']]

 step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact',
      projectName: 'generic-cucumber-report',
      filter: 'target/cucumber-html-reports/**/*',
      selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: job.getId()]]);

 publishHTML(target: [allowMissing: false, keepAll: true, reportDir:   'target/cucumber-html-reports/', 
        reportFiles: 'feature-overview.html', reportName: 'Test results'])

def failures = countFailures()
if(failures > 0){
    error '${failures} test failures reported'
}
}

def countFailures() {
  sh "ls functional-tests/target/*.json | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '\$!ba' -e 's/\\n/,/g' > filelist.txt"
  def txt = readFile "filelist.txt"
  def count = 0
  txt.split(",") each { jsonFile ->
    def text = readFile jsonFile
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(text) 
    count = count + countMatches(json,"status","failed")
  }
  return count
}
```

The issue can be seen in the countfailures method.  I read a list of files from the WS, and loop through the names.  When I try to readFile them though I get the FNF.

Comment: Can you post the readfile step?

Comment: And the code surrounding it, I should've added.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, either I don't know how to set notifications on SO thread updates or SO doesn't have the notification I need.

Comment: And ... I'm stumped. Nothing is jumping out at me. I didn't think a Pipeline step like readFile would work inside a collection iterating method like each {} but that's another issue entirely.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this peace of code and you will get the latest artefact from current build.

```
step ([$class: 'CopyArtifact', projectName: 'Pipeline', filter: '**.txt', selector: [$class: 'SpecificBuildSelector', buildNumber: env.BUILD_NUMBER]])
```